# Is Firebase Database searchable using objects instead of references, with AngularFire $firebaseArray $keyAt(recordOrIndex)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

After a user logs in using `$firebaseAuth`, Google sends the user's displayName, email, and photoURL. I then want to look up the user's account in my Firebase database. I can't use `$getRecord(key)` because Google doesn't tell me the user's key. It appears that I should use `$keyAt(recordOrIndex)`, and then use `$getRecord(key)`. `$keyAt(recordOrIndex)` works fine with an index. `$keyAt(recordOrIndex)` works fine with a record that I retrieved with `$getRecord(key)`. I can't get `$keyAt(recordOrIndex)` to work with an object that I made from the user data that Google returned using `$firebaseAuth`.

I tried both the complete object (displayName, email, photoURL) and an object consisting of only the email address. The latter is what I would prefer to use. Neither worked.

```
app.controller('LoginModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$uibModalInstance', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $location, $uibModalInstance, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, $firebaseAuth) {

  // Create Firebase3 reference
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();

  // Set up Firebase Auth
  $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth();
  var authData = $scope.authObj.$getAuth();
  $scope.authData = authData;

  // Google OAuth login handler
  $scope.loginGoogle = function() {
    $scope.authData = null;
    $scope.error = null;
    $scope.authObj.$signInWithPopup("google")
    .then(function(authData) {
      $scope.authData = authData;
      console.log(authData);
      console.log("Your displayName is:", authData.user.displayName);
      console.log("Your email is:", authData.user.email);
      console.log("Your photoURL is:", authData.user.photoURL);

      var record = {
        displayName: authData.user.displayName,
        email: authData.user.email,
        photoURL: authData.user.photoURL
      };

      var emailObject = {
        email: authData.user.email
      };

      // look up account
      var users = $firebaseArray(ref.child('users'));
      users.$loaded()
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Array loaded!");
        var key1 = users.$keyAt(1);
        console.log(key1); // -Khi6OxAo339ye6xoG3i
        var record = users.$getRecord(key1);
        console.log(record); // Object with displayName, email, and photoURL
        var key1 = users.$keyAt(record);
        console.log(key1); // -Khi6OxAo339ye6xoG3i
        var objectKey = users.$keyAt(object);
        console.log(objectKey); // null
        var emailKey = users.$keyAt(emailObject);
        console.log(emailKey); // null
      });

      $uibModalInstance.close(); // close modal window
      $location.path('/languagetwo/'); // return to the homepage
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });
  };
```

Should I use `$firebaseObject` instead of `$firebaseArray`:

```
var user = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child( SOMETHING HERE? ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be no, you can't search Firebase Database using AngularFire. (Maybe AngularFire 2 has search, I didn't look.) What I did instead was to use "plain vanilla" Firebase:

```
var users = firebase.database().ref('users');
users.orderByChild('email').equalTo(authData.user.email).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

The first line sets up the Firebase `ref` and is the similar to as before, except that I'm going straight to the `users` array, instead of using `$FirebaseArray` to get to the `users` array.

The second line is a completely different syntax. First, you have to specify the order that you want the returned object to be in. Yes, it returns an object, not an array. I tried `snapshot.val().length()` and found that it's not an array. What `orderByChild('email')` does is to access the `'email'` property of the objects in the `'users'` array.

Next we do the query. `equalTo(authData.user.email)` returns only the objects in which the email address from `$FirebaseAuth` equals the email address in our `'users'` array.

Next, `once('value')` creates a promise and waits for the async data. I tried using `on()` but couldn't get it to work, too many arguments or something. `once()` requires an argument, which can be `value`, `child_added`, `child_changed`, `child_removed`, or `child_moved`. The `value` argument is for getting data from a location without changing the child nodes.

We can then set up our `then` promise fulfillment. You can call the returned data anything. Here it's called `snapshot`.

Lastly `snapshot.val()` provides the data from the database, looking just like it does in the Firebase Console.